# Conference call combining regular Skype and Skype for Business callers

Tags: skype, skype-for-business

If you use Skype for Business, apparently it is [not possible](https://www.skypefeedback.com/forums/299913-generally-available/suggestions/9747264-group-call-with-normal-skype-members) to have a conference call and include regular Skype callers. I would like to be able to include both Skype for Business and regular Skype callers on a call. Can I do this with regular Skype, so I'd initiate the call in regular Skype and add Skype for Business callers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the opposite: Use Skype for Business [=SfB] and (if not disabled by the SfB Administrator) your remote users invited could join as guests here with the Skype for Business Webclient which is asked to be downloaded during the join process.

Comment: Yes, I was able to have the conference call as you describe. I am not sure the regular Skype user had to download anything to run the Webclient, but forgot to ask during the call.